# Unable to resolve cancel button

Tags: protractor

We have an admin page where you can save/cancel a user creation. Our protractor test are trying to check the presence of cancel button.

The admin page contains references. However the test case fail on the CI server as below,

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3110

Comment: None of those picture exists, and even so a **text** [mcve] is required.

Comment: Have you tried using the page refresh method? http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.refresh